# Mysql: Some services stop automatically if there are not in use by other services or programs

Tags: mysql

Mysql service can not start, some error happens:

```
The Service on local computer started and then stopped ,Some services stop automatically if there are not in use by other services or programs.
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow below steps solved my problem.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Restart service, success!!!